# How to set redirect?

Tags: react-router-dom

I have Switch component

```
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/contacts" exact>
                <ContactsPage />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/add" exact>
                <AddContactForm />
            </Route>
            <Redirect to="/contacts" />
        </Switch>
```

Now when I go to /contacts/add it redirects me to /contacts.
But I need to do redirect only if no one of routes is true.
So how to do that?

Comment: According to the API docs: "a `<Redirect>` with no `from` prop will always match the current location." (see: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch/children-node) In addition `/contacts/add` doesn't match any of the `exact` routes you've provided, so the `<Redirect>` resolves as a fallback. Alternatively, if all you're trying to do is provide a default in the event that no matches are found it should be enough just to add a `<Route>` with no props.

Comment: thanks to you my friend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write whole route not only /add -> /contact/add

```js
<Switch>
  <Route path="/contacts/add" exact>
    <AddContactForm />
  </Route>
  <Route path="/contacts" exact>
    <ContactsPage />
  </Route>
  <Redirect to="/contacts" />
</Switch>
```

Or if you want to split global router to few small routers

```js
// Router.js
<Switch>
  <Route path="/contacts"> // remove exact
    <ContactsPage />
  </Route>
  <Redirect to="/contacts" />
</Switch>
```

then inside Contacts page:

```js
// ContactsPage.js
<Switch>
  <Route path="/contacts/add" exact>
    <AddContactForm />
  </Route>
  <Route path="/contacts" exact>
    <Contacts />
  </Route>
</Switch>
```